# Update query from two unrelated tables

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column in a table. The update value should be retrieved from another table. The query I made is statement:

```
update db1.t1 set location=(select countryName from db1.t1, db2.t2 where t1.num 
between t2.beginNum AND t2.endNum limit 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table t1 for update in FROM clause.
```

Then, when I removed the table name `t1` from the `FROM` clause

```
update db1.t1 set location=(select countryName from db2.t2 where num 
between t2.beginNum AND t2.endNum limit 1)
```

The query worked but I am not sure if it worked correctly. As far as I know, I must specify both tables in the `FROM` clause if I am retrieving from more than 1 table. The two tables I work in do not have any common column. But, there is a value in `t1` that can be found between two values in `t2`. Is the second query absolutely correct ? How the query would know that `num` after the `where` clause is from the first table ? I am afraid that I get wrong values.

Comment: if you can't check the data to be 100% sure, you can try go to SQLFiddle.com and make the same test to see if your query is working or not

Comment: Do you have the amount of rows that changed after you ran the query? It looks like you haven't set a condition for the table you are actually updating, so this will attempt to set every record in location to the same thing if your subquery returned one record(I think, either that or nothing happens), otherwise it'd fall over due to your recordset sizes not matching. Also if you need to get countryNames from 2 tables, you will have to do a `UNION ALL` in this scenario so all the results will be in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

The two queries do something different.

The first is attempting to assign an arbitrary `t2.CountryName` to each location in t1.  It would never assign a NULL value, because there is probably some `t1.num` that meets the conditions.   when `t1.num` does not meet the `between` conditions.  The two references to `db1.t1` in the first query are different references, so you have an implicit `cross join` between the tables.

The second is assigning an arbitrary `t2.CountryName` to location where the `num` value on the row meets the condition.  For other rows, NULL would be assigned.

My guess is that the second query is really what you want to do.